# Xcode 5 - Tabs at the top

Tags: ios, ios7, tabs

I wanna put "tabs" at the top of the view and I don't find in object library... does anyone knows? Thanks for the help.

Examples here:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img829/1808/47bw.jpg

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img822/7048/oaum.jpg

Comment: There's a [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  But I prefer to implement with UIButtons.

Comment: Yes, @trick14 is Correct. It will be much easier to add onto your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between navigational tabs like the second screen shot has and just a "tabbed" division of information like the first. The first one stays a single screen while the second one could also be considered an application that has different subviews under that tabbed navigation. The first screen is trivial and you should do this with UIViews with UILabels nested into them.

The second screen is more interesting. I don't think it's a good idea to use the built in tabbed navigation handlers because it's just not a good fit for that kind of layout. You could do it but you're writing a lot of code to get it completely like you want it. But if you would want to you could divide the screen with custom containers and trigger segues in the bottom part from the UIButtons you put on top and it's a pretty good way to handle those kind of segues from within Interface Builder.

[image: Image from the Sandmoose.com tutorial]

More information:

- http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html